# Rig not aligned with the model

Tags: rigging, bones

I created a character model and fully rigged it. I used the mirror modifier during modeling and the rig is (when in edit mode) exactly the same on both left and right. However, when I go to pose mode, the left hand is still rigged correctly, but the in the right hand, the rigs of the fingers are not aligned with the fingers anymore (see the image). Moving these bones cause the fingers to deform.

How can I fix this without having to re-rig the entire model?

[image: Rig error]

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I fixed it. How it happened is unclear to me, but changes in Edit mode of the rig did not affect the model.

Comment: Changing the rig in edit mode shouldn't affect the model. That's expected behavior.